# asyncio.sleep() is causing a runtimeerror when made to run

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am currently learning python. I am trying to create a game which involves the asyncio.sleep() function. I have declared a function which allows me to print a string with a time interval between each letter. Whenever I run it, the same error shows :

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'sleep' was never awaited
  sleep(time)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
i
```

This is my code so far:

```
# Importing necessary modules
from asyncio import sleep
from keyboard import wait
# Getting username and verifying that it is not already taken.
username,new_username = input(f"Welcome to intergalactic space adventures.\nPlease enter your chosen username : "),False
while not new_username:
    with open(f"intergalactic_usernames.txt","r") as i_u:
        usernames = i_u.readlines()
    if f"\n{username.lower().strip()}\n" not in usernames and f"\n{username.lower().strip()}" not in usernames:
        del i_u,usernames
        with open(f"intergalactic_usernames.txt","a") as i_u:
            i_u.write(f"\n{username.lower().strip()}")
        new_username = True
    else:
        username = input(f"Sorry, that username is already taken.\nPlease enter another one : ")
del new_username
# Introducing player to game and describing surroundings
def dramatic_print(string,time=0.25):
    for letter in string:
        print(f"{letter}",end=f"")
        sleep(time)
```

I tried enabling tracemalloc but could not, as this error was displayed :

```
python3 : The term 'python3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python3 -x tracemalloc
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python3:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I reinstalled Python 3.11 from python.org, but this error is still not resolved.

Comment: (1) You don't use asynchronous functionality (except `sleep`). Replace it by `time.sleep`. (2) Instead of `python3` use what you used to run the code normally (if you need tracemalloc one day).

Comment: You don't use `asyncio` properly, as the first part of the warning points out : _RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'sleep' was never awaited_.